# Create union tupe from two arrays or similar

Tags: typescript

I get string values from my backend like this:

```
"Approved", "Pending", "Expired"..
```

And so on. I can push all strings to an array and I have:

```
["Approved", "Pending", "Expired"]
```

The backend can send back different kind of values in both name and in amount depending on what is available. There is maximum of 5 different values that will not change, but it could return less than mentioned amount and in different combinations.

In the frond end, these values are translated to the current users language. We might get the following:

```
["Godkänd", "Pågående", "Utgått"]
```

Now, when I try to connect back to the backend I cannot use the translated values and I need to use the first array values. To make it easier I was thinking about "connecting" the original values with the translated ones in some kind of union type. Pseudo code:

```
 ["Approved" | "Godkänd", "Pending" | "Pågående", "Expired" | "Utgått"]
```

Or something similar. How to do it, and what is the "best" way to do it?

Comment: Where are these strings fetched from? You can’t have constant string types unless the strings somehow originate in code.

Comment: The strings is from backend and will always be the same in its definition- only thing that can vary is the amount. Sometimes it might return 4 different types, or 3 but never more than 5 different. So it means the combination can vary as well. In frontend these are translated by our api and will always be the same for the specific language, but can vary per user.

Comment: Don't send strings either way, send IDs.

Comment: It all depends on the situation. Generally IDs is best, but this issue comes from user input from a search box in front-end where they will search for the localized state name per the example, and sent to our filtering component for string-check with our data object from the backend. Otherwise it would be easy to fix using unique Ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's discussion in the comments as to whether this is a *good* solution to your problem, but ultimately here is one way of zipping together two const tuples:

```
type TupleIndices<T extends any[]> = Exclude<keyof T, keyof Array<any>>;

type UnionZip<T extends any[], U extends any[]> = { [I in TupleIndices<T | U>]: T[I] | U[I] };

type Zipped = UnionZip<["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]>;

const list: Zipped = ["a", "e", "c"]; // OK
const elem = list[1]; // elem: "b" | "e"

const list2: Zipped = ["a", "b", "c"]; // OK
const list3: Zipped = ["d", "e", "f"]; // OK
const list4: Zipped = ["d", "e", "22"]; // ERR
const list5: Zipped = ["a", "b"]; // ERR;

type Zipped2 = UnionZip<[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]>; // [1 | 4, 2 | 5], only covers the first two elements
type Zipped3 = UnionZip<["a" | "b", "c" & "d"], ["e", "f"]>; // ["a" | "b" | "e", "f"]
```